# Django ModelForm: how do I pre-populate data for a ModelForm overriding a field's widget? (Some working, some not.)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model form with a number of fields that need to use widgets other than the default widget for the model data type.

Loading the update form before adding custom widgets, all the data pre-populates for the current object correctly. As soon as I add a custom widget for any field, the pre-population for that field breaks.

For example, this works as expected:
class ChecklistForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
        model = Checklist
        fields = [
            "expected_time", #TimeField
            "completed", #BooleanField, nullable
        ]
```

But I want control over the widgets used. I'd like the boolean `completed` field to render as a checkbox even though it is nullable, so I add:

class ChecklistForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Checklist
    fields = [
        "expected_time", #TimeField
        "completed", #BooleanField, nullable
        "date", #DateField
    ]
    widgets = {
        'expected_time': forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M',attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'completed': forms.CheckboxInput(),
        'date': forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%Y'), attrs={'placeholder':'Select a date', 'type':'date'}),
    }
```

When I load an update form, `completed` pre-populates correctly, while `expected_time` and `date` do not.

Why? And is there a way to pre-populate these fields automatically?